# PyCharm "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio""

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm attempting to download the package cx-oracle with `pip install cx-oracle` but keep getting the error:

```
 building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "C:\Users\cn202607\PycharmProjects\Balance\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cn202607\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-dbhkgavk\\Cython\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().re
place('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cn202607\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-record-p9eixlj_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix C:\Users\cn202607\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-_nao7s
pg\overlay --compile --install-headers C:\Users\cn202607\PycharmProjects\Balance\venv\include\site\python3.8\Cython" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\cn202607\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-dbhkgavk\Cython\
```

I can install it just fine locally with the command prompt using
`pip install cx-oracle --user` but inside of pycharm it gives me that error. I unfortunately don't have the privlidges to install the build tools like everyone suggests but given that it installs locally just fine that doesn't seem to be the problem so I'm looking for other solutions. The problem seems to be the PyCharm environment but I'm unsure why.

Comment: Can you please share which python version you are running outside of pycharm and can you also add the full error output you are getting to your question? This will help to find an adequate answer

Comment: Fixed the issue. Seems to be a problem with Python 3.8. Switched my interpreter to 3.6 and it works now.